# Lock some text in vim to prevent modifications

Tags: vim, locking, buffer

I'm looking for a way to prevent the modification of *a part* of a vim buffer. I know it is possible to lock buffer to prevent all modifications inside, but I would like to do the same for just a few lines,  or a paragraph.

Any idea if this is possible ?

Cheers,
V

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, as I know,  vim can not do that. The text in vim buffer is just a "string" without any property can be attached to them. So "readonly" can be only to whole buffer, but not specific characters, although emacs is able to add text properties to let some characters in buffer readonly.

On the other handle, if you really want to edit something and make it not affect the other buffer content. There should be an alternate way, although is not elegant.

1.create a temp buffer with "setlocal buftype=nofile", insert the text you want to edit into that buffer.
2.show that buffer on other window(need split firstly)
3.edit the temp buffer.
4.when you close that buffer, "merge" the result in the real buffer, and replace the text you want to edit.

So, you need to do that via some key binding and vim scripting, not an easy way.

Answer (score 1):

If the "protected" region of text is readily defined (i.e. by its position in the file, or a regular expression) you could try writing a `BufWritePre` function that checks this region and throws an error if it has been modified. I resorted to this when I wanted to prevent saving a file with an invalid fold structure.

Presumably this would involve saving the original text in a variable when the file is loaded, and this may have performance implications.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin called [narrow region](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3075) that edits selected text leaving intact the rest

Comment: That's not exactly what I need, but it's good to know this plugin, thank you !